# How to keep sentries and templars in the center of death balll?

Tags: starcraft-2

Couple of posts about sentries usages ([Effective use of Sentry in Starcraft 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/effective-use-of-sentry-in-starcraft-2)) mention it is good to keep sentries in the center of you army so guardian shield will cover bigger amount of units and sentries can FF opponent quicker.

Similar I can say about templars: in center they are more defended and can quicker cast storm or feedback.

But even though I keep sentries on the same short-key as other gateway units they tend to spread out asides.

With templars that is even worse: they are slower and I keep templars usually on a separate short-key. As a result they often either behind and come to the battle too late or they are unprotected at all...

How you deal with this to keep sentries in the center of the death-ball and templars close to it?

Thanks a lot for any advise!

P.S. I do realize that keeping casters in PvT is vulnerable to EMPs, but in my current level (top gold/medium platinum) I'm not EMPed too often and that is not a problem for me yet.

Answer (score 2):

If your micro isn't up to par one way you can keep sentries close to the centre of the deathball is by giving them a move (follow) command on your collossi by right-clicking on them. Keep them in a separate hotkey numver from your army so you don't accidentally cause them to unfollow.
as soon as you cast GS right click on the collossi again and they will stay underneath it.

Templars are a different story cause they're so slow. Still, I recommend keeping them ona separate hotkey from the rest of your army and ordering them to follow the collossi. Or, order your ARMY to follow the templars when your not in combat and don't expect an attack.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I am a Top Platinum Player, actually I won many many games in Platinum Rank 1 vs. Diamond but stopped playing.

**Sentries**

With Sentries in Deathball it correct what you say, keep them in the middle is good so you can force field well and shield everything. I never experienced this problems you encounter with sentries, I just placed them in the deathball and as soon as you start the fight you anyway activate more than 1 shield. Since it would be stupid to have one shield which covers all units. And of course you will do some moving with your melee army and your colossus. So as soon as the fight starts you try to hide colossus behind Stalkers which are killing the vikings or any other anti-air air-units. And your Zealots are rushing towards enemy land units, so you spread anyway a bit. So simply keep the number of sentries up. If you have 200/200 supply which is mostly army than you should have at least 7 sentries which should cover your deathball well.

**Templars:**

Templars are used for storming biological units, mostly used vs marines & marauders or Zerg units. To be honest I didn't use templars often and that's not good, but from watching streams you will see how they use them. Often they seperate a group of templars coming from behind or from the side in the fight. Of course you can keep some in your deathball, but don't expect the enemy to be that stupid to run into your ball.
Alternatively templars are used from a surprise position like dropped from ship or sitting on a cliff nearby and morphed right after. To catch the enemy army before he perfectly splits them to fight your deathball.

And also you will not get EMP'd often in early Diamond - at least happened really rarely to me.

Comment: Generally you will see high-level protoss activate two guardian shields.  It has the benefit of additional coverage and prevents you from losing GS if your single sentry dies.
Generally you should have zealots in front of sentries, but there is no better way than to select them all and move back.
Templars should be near the front for feedback

Comment: only 2? they simply hit the button fast, sometimes more than 2 but never less ;) I never said only 1

Comment: I meant exactly two.  Three is generally a waste.  Depending on the sentry count you could use a single GS, but in PvT especially you'll see two